# Выяснить день недели из БД

Tags: php, mysql

В БД время хранится как юникс время.

`date('l', $date)` все равно выводит сегодняшний день недели.
Как это исправить?

Answer (score 1):

Какой у вас тип переменной `$date`?

```
<?php
$date=142193589;
echo gettype($date)."\n";
echo date("l",$date);
?>
```

Comment: gettype($date) выдает string

echo date("l",$date); всегда выдает четверг

Comment: Тип не имеет значение. Если он, конечно, не boolean или еще что.